# Can't send mail from localhost with xampp

Tags: php, apache, email

I'am trying to send mail from localhost with xampp so I  configured my xampp php.ini and sendmail.ini file to use my Gmail account for sending email from my PHP script with the help of this two links: [link1](http://www.journaldunet.com/developpeur/pratique/developpement/18069/comment-configurer-xampp-pour-envoyer-des-mails-depuis-un-localhost.html) and [link2](http://blog.pierre-roels.com/2012/10/envoyer-des-emails-en-localhost-avec-xampp-windows/) .

But, when I want to send my Contact Form, I have the message of validation **Your message has been sent** but in *my mailBox*, I don't found no thing.

```
    [mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = ******@gmail.com

sendmail_path = \C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\ -t

mail.add_x_header=On

    [sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

smtp_ssl=auto

error_logfile=error.log

auth_username=******@gmail.com

auth_password=**********

force_sender=******@gmail.com
```

What have I missed? Why can't I receive my mail?

Comment: Probably your message is considered SPAM or delayed. It also makes sense to take a look into your http servers error log file. The statement "Your message has been sent" is something you implemented, so we cannot judge if you did a correct error detection and handling. Most likely _not_. You need to post your actual code for us to help with that.

Comment: try phpmailer its very easy